# Why does import wx throw an error on python?

Tags: python, wxpython

I’m developing a bot over discord to open a webpage remotely (my company site, over a tv). I am basing it off of another bot I found. Here is a code snippet:

````
import wx 
import wx.html2 

class MyBrowser(wx.Dialog): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds): 
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds) 
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
        self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self) 
        sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10) 
        self.SetSizer(sizer) 
        self.SetSize((700, 700))

@client.slash_command(name="webwindow", description="open a web withow the url in a window", guild_ids=g)
async def webwindow_command(interaction: Interaction, url: str):
    if interaction.channel.name == channel_name:
        if url.startswith("http://") or url.startswith("https://"):
            try:
                await interaction.channel.send("web window started")
                app = wx.App() 
                dialog = MyBrowser(None, -1)
                dialog.browser.LoadURL(url) 
                dialog.Show() 
                app.MainLoop()
            except Exception as e:
                await interaction.channel.send("```try other link```")
                await interaction.channel.send(e)
        else:
            await interaction.channel.send("you need to put https:// or http://")
````

And it threw an error.

I was expecting it to work, I didn’t really find any issues but it said: no module named “wx”.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I fixed the code formatting. Please check the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for future reference. Multi-line code needs *three* backticks *both before and after, on a separate line in each case*. Anyway, when asking about an error message, please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message that corresponds to a [mre]. If there is an error from trying to `import` something, then we do not need to see any of the code that tries to use the module - all of that is after the error, so it's not relevant.

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand why a Discord bot is using a GUI library. Do you want other people to send commands to your bot, and have it open a window on **your** computer? Why? It cannot open a window on their computer, because a Discord bot only sends data back to the Discord server - it doesn't know anything about the other computer.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. Yes, I want other people to be able to control the tv (e.g. when they present, they can show their website).

Comment: "but it said: no module named “wx”." Well, that seems pretty self-explanatory. `wx` is not part of the standard library; it needs to be installed, just like discord.py.

Comment: So I just have to run pip install wx? 
(Sorry, I’m a newbie at this).